She finds it boring at home. vs. She finds it boring being at home

She finds it boring at home.  vs. She finds it boring being at home.

What's the idiomatic usage? I think the second one looks grammatically right.

If you say "I find it interesting at work", I suppose a pedant might respond "You find what boring?" But lots of people say things like that, so I wouldn't worry about it. If you want to play ultra-safe, though, just rephrase to get rid of that potentially problematic "dummy it" with "I find being at work interesting".

@FumbleFingers So both of my examples are okay?

Yes, they are. The second version is just a little clearer.

@FumbleFingers - In that situation I would say that someone who responds "You find what  boring?" is a fool, rather than a pedant'.

@FumbleFingers - In that situation I would say that someone who responds "You find what boring?" is a fool, rather than a 'pedant'.

It is such a dummy too.

@TimR - I saw what you did there :-)

It might appear pedantic, but it depends on context. "She likes playing video games at her friends'. She finds it boring at home. She doesn't have any good games but her friends have all the latest." If the sentences are intended to stand alone, there's not really a difference because "it" must refer to being at home in general, but the question doesn't say what the context is.
